# C# 8 Default Interfaces: Can they inherit as well?

Tags: c#

I know that C# 8 is still under heavy development but I was concerned/excited about the default interfaces announcement. The examples I've seen all are represented like so:

```
public interface IMyDefaultInterFace
{
    public int SomeDefaultFunction(int charge, int multiplier)
    {
       return charge * multiplier;
    }
}
```

This is great but what I wonder (and hope) is that this will be possible as well:

```
public interface ISomeOtherInterface 
{
   int charge { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyDefaultInterFace : ISomeOtherInterface
{
    int SomeDefaultFunction(int multiplier)
    {
       return charge * multiplier;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know if this is the plan? I know there's some potential complexities involved due to scoping or whatnot but the former doesn't seem to offer any significant advantages while the latter provides some powerful possibilities.

Like I said I know it's early. Maybe some MS lurker has some inside info?

Comment: I’m not sure what scoping issues you’re referring to.  The `change` property is in scope and bindable as an interface call.  There’s no reason why this shouldn’t work.

Comment: Yeah, considering the proposed feature was meant to be similar to Java's Default Implementations, I can't think of any reason that it would be different from this perspective.

Comment: @MikeStrobel - fair enough. I try not to assume I understand all the ins and outs of these kinds of features.